# 정말이 가족과 각정하요 사랑합니다 does this make sense?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am trying to say 'I really do care and love this family'

I have also tried:
나는 정말로이 가족을 돌보고 사랑합니다

Tandem and google translate and naver all seem to have different ideas on how it should be spelt.

Comment: Your question needs more details: (1) What does "care" mean in that sentence? "To care" has multiple meanings, so you should be more specific. (2) Who will be the listener? Korean has several speech levels.

Comment: Thanks for that Klmo, the listener is my partners parents, for a permission to marry.  Care as in deep consideration., thanks for your response, 존댓말 will be used.

Comment: Then, we can use the verb 아끼다 to express "to care." I have more questions: Does "this family" refer to your partner's family or your family? 이 가족 sounds like someone else's family. What sentences will you add before and after that sentence? Can you give any other information regarding the context?

Comment: Wow thanks you are a gold mine of information and consideration, I hope to return the favour in anyway i can. As for the context I will send through the full script I hope to use, I could not ask you to amend the full script that would be rude of me, but for the sake of context I will send it through

Comment: 'So, you may already be aware that I have been wanting to spend more time with the whole family and I have wanted to say that I really do care and love this family.'
I want to say that I really do Love your daughter, Soyeon.
So much so that I want to marry her, I want to commit myself to her for the rest of our lives.

Comment: 시드니에서 가족과 더 많은 시간을 보내고 싶어 정말이 가족과 아끼다 사랑합니다. 저는 너무 많이 그녀와 결혼하고 싶어. 그녀는 놀라운 소녀이고 당신은 그녀를 키우는 훌륭한 일을 해왔고, 그녀는 매일 내 마음을 녹였습니다.

Comment: Thats what I have pieced together so far, with the addition of 아끼다. I am not worried if it's not perfect as it will is it will likely get a few laughs afterwards, I'm just aiming at getting the idea across, in plain simple language. as for the question of whether it is our family or their family. It is my partners family so they are future in-laws.

Comment: Also thanks again, sorry about swamping you with information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit strange to say "I love you" when "you" refers to her family (not your own family) unless you have been living for a long time with her family. I would just say "I really care for and love your daughter," which can be translated as "저는 따님을 정말로 아끼고 사랑합니다."

As for the script, you should be more specific about whom you are referring to. If she lives with her parents only, you can say the following to her parents:

이미 아실지도 모르겠지만 저는 따님은 물론 아버님, 어머님과도 더 오래 함께하기를 원해 왔습니다. 그리고 따님을 얼마나 아끼는지, 이렇게 아름다운 따님을 훌륭하게 길러 주신 아버님, 어머님을 얼마나 소중히 생각하는지 말씀드리고 싶었습니다. 따님을 진심으로 사랑해 왔고 여전히 사랑하기에 이제 따님의 동반자가 되어 평생 동안 따님과 동고동락하며 살고 싶습니다. 저를 새 식구로 맞이하여 주시지 않겠습니까?

Because I do not know her family, I am not sure whether this expression will be appropriate; at least I can say that they will know what you mean. It is difficult for me to translate the whole paragraph, so I would just list most of the words I use above:

- 이미: already
- 알다: to know
- -시- (as in 아시다): an ending of a word used for the subject honorifics of an action or state
- 모르다: to have no idea, do not know, etc.
- 저: I or me (honorific)
- 따님: one's daughter (not your own daughter) (honorific)
- 물론: without need to say
- 아버님: one's father (not your earthly father) (honorific)
- 어머님: one's mother (not your earthly mother) (honorific)
- 더: more
- 오래: (for) a long time
- 함께하다: to share an idea or time, spend time with someone working on something, etc.
- 원하다: to want, to wish, to hope, etc.
- 오다 (as in 날이 밝아 온다): an auxiliary verb used to indicate that the act or state mentioned in the preceding statement is continued
- 그리고: and (as a sentence or clause connector)
- 얼마나: how much or in a great and enormous degree in terms of a state or feeling
- 아끼다: to take care of and value someone or something
- 이렇게: like this, this much, this way, etc.
- 아름답다: beautiful
- 훌륭하다: excellent, respectable, praiseworthy, etc.
- 기르다: to raise (as in raising a child)
- 소중하다: very precious
- 생각하다: to think, regard, etc.
- 말씀드리다: to tell someone (in a respectful manner) (honorific)
- 진심: a sincere heart
- 사랑하다: to love
- 여전히: still
- 이제: now (not right now)
- 동반자: a partner (as in a partner for life)
- 되다: to become
- 평생: one's entire life
- 동안: during, for, or while
- 동고동락하다: to share the pleasures and pains of life
- 살다: to live
- 싶다 (as in 가고 싶다): an auxiliary adjective used to indicate that the speaker has an intention or desire to do what the preceding statement describes
- 새: new
- 식구: a family member
- 맞이하다: to accept someone as a new family member

Comment: Thanks so much, that was an astonishing amount of time and care you have put in, please do let me know if i can repay you in any way

Comment: It didn't take so long; you don't have to do something for me. I wish you a long and happy life.